# How to boost the performance of a custom shortcut action Handler in Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, handler, vaadin, shortcut

given an example from the Book of Vaadin (*Chapter 5.21 Table Component, Navigation in Editable Mode*):

```
// Keyboard navigation
class KbdHandler implements Handler {
    Action tab_next = new ShortcutAction("Tab",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null);
    Action tab_prev = new ShortcutAction("Shift+Tab",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB,
            new int[] {ShortcutAction.ModifierKey.SHIFT});
    Action cur_down = new ShortcutAction("Down",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ARROW_DOWN, null);
    Action cur_up   = new ShortcutAction("Up",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ARROW_UP,   null);
    Action enter   = new ShortcutAction("Enter",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER,      null);
    public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
        return new Action[] {tab_next, tab_prev, cur_down,
                             cur_up, enter};
    }

    public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender,
                             Object target) {
        if (target instanceof TextField) {
            // Move according to keypress
            int itemid = (Integer) ((TextField) target).getData();
            if (action == tab_next || action == cur_down)
                itemid++;
            else if (action == tab_prev || action == cur_up)
                itemid--;
            // On enter, just stay where you were. If we did
            // not catch the enter action, the focus would be
            // moved to wrong place.

            if (itemid >= 0 && itemid < table.size()) {
                TextField newTF = valueFields.get(itemid);
                if (newTF != null)
                    newTF.focus();
            }
        }
    }
}


// Panel that handles keyboard navigation
Panel navigator = new Panel();
navigator.addStyleName(Reindeer.PANEL_LIGHT);
navigator.addComponent(table);
navigator.addActionHandler(new KbdHandler());
```

Actually the *navigator.addCompoent(table)* must be replaced with navigator.setContent(table), cause Panel has not an *addComponent* method, but this is not the point.

The point is that I have noticed that using a custom shortcut action handler lowers the performance of the focus change from a field to the next one when you hold down the action key. The reason of this is because when using this custom Handler implementation, Vaadin makes a request every time one of the shortcut keys is typed (in this example, when TAB, Shift+TAB, Arrow_Up, Arrow_Down and ENTER are typed).

This gives the following result:

[image]

Starting from the "Numeric Field" with value "0" I have typed TAB two times and at the same time two requests were made to the server.

In contrast, if using no custom shortcut action Handler, the previous two TABs would result into this:

[image]

No unnecessary requests. This is not a problem while the typing is slow, but as I said before, if you hold down the TAB key, hundreds requests will be made, and you will notice the difference. Enhancing the user experience allowing the user easily navigate through the table fields here has a cost in performance from this point of view.

So my question is, is there a way to disable this unnecessary requests when using a custom shortcut action Handler in Vaadin?

Comment: Recently I had similar problem but with combobox - not textfield. I wanted to send request to server only when user didn't type since certain amount of time. I've used AsyncFilterComboBox https://github.com/zero11it/vaadin-asyncfiltercombobox . I suggest you to write your own custom async text field that won't send ValueChangeEvent immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I am reading the Book of Vaadin, didn't arrive at the Custom Components chapter yet, but gonna do that soon, then I guess I'll give it a try!